# Implementing stack in python by using lists as stacks 

Tags: python

I am create a stack demo with some functionality:

```
( Method ) __init__(self, n) => How can I initial the fix  n len of stack. ?
( Method ) IsEmpty      => Done by using lists as stacks 
( Method ) IsFull       => Done by using lists as stacks 
( Method ) Push         => Done by using lists as stacks 
( Method ) Pop          => Done by using lists as stacks
```

The code i am doing

```
 class Stack(object) :

   def __init__(self) :
    self.items = []
   def push(self, item) :
    self.items.append(item)

   def pop(self) :
    return self.items.pop()

   def isEmpty(self) :
    return (self.items == []) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demoStack = Stack()
    demoStack.push(1)
    print demoStack.items
```

Anyboday know to do this?

thanks

Comment: Please learn python, give it a try and if it does not work, ask a more concrete question.

Comment: This is an extremely poorly worded question.

Comment: Your question becomes more rediculous the more you edit it.

Comment: @IEnAk, [Dive into Python](http://diveintopython.org/) is a good place to start learning the language.  It is both free and complete.

Comment: I update my question ,please have a look. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's list probably already has everything you want.  If you want some additional functionality like limiting max number of objects you should subclass it or wrap around it with another class.

Comment: maarons could you tell me more .

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Using lists as stacks](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks) in python.

Answer (score 1):

Python has it built-in, see [Using Lists as Stacks](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks). It sounds like you might benefit from the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/), as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> stack = []
>>> print stack
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> val = stack.pop()
>>> print stack
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> val
9
>>>
```